# ¿Los objetos pueden tener el mismo nombre en una clase?

Tags: c#, poo

Estoy comenzando en el mundo de la programación, he nombrado dos objetos con el mismo nombre y no hay error.

Tengo un método que instancia la clase con esta línea:

```
clsDatos objdatos = new clsDatos();
```

... y otro método que instancia la clase con la misma línea.

Es esto buena práctica de programación?

Comment: Puedes especificar el lenguaje en el cual programas? la mayoría no debería permitirlo. Puedes también agregar el código de ejemplo?

Comment: Revisa si _realmente tienen el mismo nombre_. Es decir: `miVariable` no es igual a `mivariable` ... o, en .NET, puesto que permite símbolos especiales como acentos, podrías tener `telefono` y `teléfono` y las dos son distintas.

Comment: el lengua es c#, tengo un método que instancia la clase con esta linea clsDatos objdatos = new clsDatos();
y otro metodo que instancia la clase con la misma linea

Comment: @Sebastian, respecto a tu pregunta, si el nombre es el problema, renombra la nueva instancia de la clase; lo ideal es que, ya sea una variable, clase o demás variables y valores en el código posean un nombre que facilite la comprensión del código y no existan ambigüedades. Me temo que, en todo caso, tu pregunta **se basa en opiniones**. te recomiendo visitar **[centro de ayuda del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)** para mejorar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más seguro es que ambos objetos fueron declarados en forma local y no global,  de lo contrario no te lo hubiera permitido.

Es decir tienes dos funciones

```
public void funcion1() {
  int numero = 0;
}

public void funcion2() {
  int numero = 1;
}
```

Ambas funciones tienen el mismo nombre, pero al ser locales se destruyen al salir del método por lo cual solo tienen impacto dentro del mismo método, igualmente podrías hacer

```
 public void funcion1() {
  int numero = 0;
  funcion2();
}

public void funcion2() {
  int numero = 1;
}
```

Y tampoco habría problema, el problema vendría cuando declares una funcion global y una local con el mismo nombre o dos funciones locales con el mismo nombre o dos funciones globales con el mismo nombre.
El lenguaje no sabrá a cual variable con ese nombre apuntar, algunos lenguajes como java si que te permite crear variable local y variable global apuntando con un `this.` a la variable global y si se pone sin el 'this' es apuntando a la variable local.

```
private int numero;
public void funcion1() {
  int numero = 0;
  this.numero = numero //la variable global será igual a la local
}
```

Pero ningún lenguaje te permitirá crear dos variables locales o dos variables globales con el mismo nombre.

Recuerda que la mayoría de lenguaje son caseSensitive, quiere decir que diferencian entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, no es lo mismo `Numero` que `numero` ni que `NUMERO`